# Weird Native Crash - pid: 0, tid: 0 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, segmentation-fault

I am getting this weird crash on android

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.oimvo.discdj <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000001d050  /data/app/com.oimvo.discdj-2/lib/arm64/libavfilter.7.11.101.so (av_fastresampler_resample_s16+1944)
  #01  pc 000000000001c930  /data/app/com.oimvo.discdj-2/lib/arm64/libavfilter.7.11.101.so (av_fastresampler_resample_s16+120)
```

and another similar crash

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.oimvo.discdj <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000083770  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #01  pc 0000000000096ac0  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #02  pc 0000000000095878  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #03  pc 0000000000095f14  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #04  pc 000000000003c870  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #05  pc 000000000003cbc8  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
  #06  pc 000000000005df6c  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (glDeleteFramebuffers+68)
  #07  pc 0000000000021b2b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #08  pc 000000000005f873  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #09  pc 00000000000236ab  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #10  pc 000000000002334b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #11  pc 0000000000024d0f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #12  pc 0000000000028105  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+80)
  #13  pc 000000000000e349  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+140)
  #14  pc 0000000000064229  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
  #15  pc 0000000000047063  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
  #16  pc 0000000000019ded  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

both are `- signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`

first crash is happening in my native code, second is happening somewhere else

I have corrected all possible array map errors, and currently i don't have any errors of mapping

**BUT HERE I FIND THE PID AND TID "0" ZERO WHICH IS SOMETHING I CANT UNDERSTAND**

Please someone explain me why is the `pid` and `tid` 0 reported in the crash, i did checked the functions for any `array mapping errors`, but i guess here the error is related to `process/thread id`.

I checked all the `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)` questions on stackoverflow, i also encountered `SEGV_MAPERR` earlier but it was related to some fault address, but here this one is different, i get no fault address here i only suspect that the `pid`/`tid` maybe causing this error.

Any help/suggestion will be great. Thanks in advance

**Edit:** i just now noted that i have other crashes too with pid: 0, tid: 0 and maybe most android 7.0,7.1, Please let me know if someone needs more error logs, i am still confused why the pid and tid is zero

**Edit: Please try to understand the question before answering, and let me know if someone needs more info**

Comment: pid and tid cannot be zero, it just means the crash trashed the stack/heap and cannot be accurately reported. Native crashes are tricky, more info the better, debug the hell out of it ;O) Is it repeatable ? Narrow down the offending code. Try to give us a minimal example...something I did b4[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825305/how-to-debug-segv-accerr/41885866#41885866)

Comment: @JonGoodwin  Actually its repeatable, i find similar crashes, but with no useful crash reports. i read your answer in earlier searches and managed to remove SEGV_ACCERR and all fault addr SEGV_MAPERR errors, but i am unable to resolve this error neither able to spot it down for debugging

Comment: You can narrow it down by putting lots of log messages in your code, when it crashes you will know roughly where  it was and can thus narrow it down. Or attach a debugger.

Comment: @JonGoodwin You are right, but all the crashes are from android playstore. I have 5 devices in my house but non of them produces these crashes.

Comment: @JonGoodwin I sure know that i can't stop crashes, but surely i have to adapt to all possible device types and avoid practices may generate crashes. Thank for the help, i think there is no solution to this question.

Comment: I understand when people don't want to share their code, but I'm guessing you don't have *too much native code*. Try to pare it down to the bare essentials and it can be reviewed. Try to look for tools like [JniHelpers](https://github.com/spotify/JniHelpers) to make your code better.

Comment: Maybe You are using in your app 3rd Party libraries/y(f.e. Realm), and them have bugs in native code

Comment: JonGoodwin i sure will try JniHelpers.
@Wrobel i use native libraries, but i use my personally coded program, which in my mind should never result this error(i checked several times) but still it crashes

Comment: Post your gradle compile files in the question. In my case i was using third party video chat library which causes this issue.

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes i use external library, but i compiled it myself and also wrote its code, i use pre-compiled libraries not based on gradle compilation.

Comment: Ohkk can you name them so that it will be easy to track them and for which purpose you are using ?

Comment: @RahulKhurana i use ffmpeg all libraries for audio decoding

Comment: ohkk double check all the libraries and check if there is update  available.

Comment: Well i used the latest version 3.4.1

Comment: @Diljeet I too using ffmpeg in my custom audio framework and getting second crash mostly in Samsung devices,m searching  solution for long time,

Comment: @immutable I have given up on these crashes, i am currently ignoring crashes and focusing on completing the remaining features of the app. We know that we wrote error free code, but devices sometimes have bugs (because i never have any of these crashes on my devices). One advice - check the non automatic error submissions, the error logs of user submitted errors are more detailed.

Comment: I am using Android SoundPool, no ffmpeg etc, and also have this weird error logs

Comment: Any solution ???

Comment: @VMS No. Sorry its still the same situation